# GitlabCi deploy on multiple servers

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use Gitlab runner and works fine for a single server. The gitlab-ci.yml is simple:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  image: php
  tags:
      - docker
  script:
      - echo "Run tests..."
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
      - shell
    script:
      - sh deploy.sh
```

As i said this is fine for a single server but to deploy same app on another server? I tried with same gitlab-runner config (same conf.toml) but then it was only updating one of them randomly.

Is there somehow gitlab Ci to be triggered by more than 1 runner and deploy all of them according gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can register several runners (e.g. tagged *serverA* and *serverB*) from different servers and have multiple deployment jobs, each of them performed by a different runner. This is because you can set more than one tag in a job and only a runner having all the tags will be used.

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  image: php
  tags:
      - docker
  script:
      - echo "Run tests..."

deployA:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
      - shell
      - serverA
    script:
      - sh deploy.sh

deployB:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
      - shell
      - serverB
    script:
      - sh deploy.sh
```

However, take into account a situation when one of the deployment jobs fails - this would end up in you having two different versions of the code on the servers. Depending on your situation this might or might not be a problem.

Comment: yes also this could be a problem in case you use auto scaling and you are not aware of how many servers you have up and their info

Comment: If it's a problem then you should avoid this. Have only one deployment job and use a tool that will do the deployment to multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, just set up two jobs for the same stage:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:one:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Hello CI one"

deploy:two:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Hello CI two"
```

If necessary you can use `tags` on your runners to choose which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2016, you now have [Environments and deployments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/)

> Environments describe where code is deployed.
>
> Each time GitLab CI/CD deploys a version of code to an environment, a deployment is created.
>
> GitLab:
>
> - Provides a full history of deployments to each environment.
> - Tracks your deployments, so you always know what is deployed on your servers.

It does [integrates well with Prometheis](http://Bring%20your%20own%20Prometheus%20for%20the%20best%20GitLab%20-%20Kubernetes%20integrated%20experience), and, with [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#update-a-deploy-freeze-period-in-the-ui) (April 2021), you even have:

> ### Update a deploy freeze period in the UI
>
> In GitLab 13.2, we added the ability to create a [deploy freeze](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#prevent-unintentional-releases-by-setting-a-deploy-freeze) period in the project’s CI/CD settings.
>
> This capability helps teams avoid unintentional deployments, reduce uncertainty, and mitigate deployment risks.
>
> However, it was not possible to update deploy freezes.
>
> In GitLab 13.11, we are adding the ability to edit an existing deploy freeze. This way, you can update the freeze period to match your business needs.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_11/update_deploy_freeze_1.png -- Update a deploy freeze period in the UI]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#prevent-unintentional-releases-by-setting-a-deploy-freeze) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212449).

As shown in "[`gitlab-ci.yml` deployment on multiple hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568106/6309)", you can use [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors) to trigger parallel deployment on multiple environments, which means "multiple servers".