# .gitlab-ci stages execution order

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stepA:
  script:
    - echo "A"
deploy:
  script:
    - echo "1"
stepB:
  script:
    - echo "B"
```

How can I set which stage should be run in first ?
Some jobs can be run in parallel by multiple gitlab runners.
I just want to be sure step A to B are finished before running deploy stage

Comment: You question quite confusing. You want to make sure before deploy A and B step should be completed ?

Comment: yes that's it, this is what i want

Comment: Just created sample pipeline and updated the answer

Comment: Be aware. `Jobs` and `Stages` are different things. Stage is a group of jobs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is exactly what `stages` is for. You are using the word "stage" here when actually describing a "job".

Jobs in the same stage may be run in parallel (if you have the runners to support it) but stages run in order.

First define your 2 stages at the top level of the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - dist
```

Then on each job, specify the stage it belongs to:

```
stepA:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "A"
deploy:
  stage: dist
  script:
    - echo "1"
stepB:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "B"
```

Now `stepA` and `stepB` will run first (in any order or even in parallel) followed by `deploy` provided the first stage succeeds.

Comment: I have a problem: generated files by stepA and stepB files are not kept for deploy stage

Comment: What you want here is the `artifacts` and `depends` sections on the jobs. Specify the files a job produces and then specify a job that another job needs the results of with a dependency.

Comment: But how do you force the order of the two "build" stages?

Comment: @swade To correct your terminology to help googling: here there are two _jobs_ in the one "build" _stage_. You don't control the order of jobs within a stage. So if you need "stepA" to run before "stepB" then make a new stage before build and move "stepA" into the new early stage.

Comment: @SpencerPark Ah, that's a bummer. It's just a nitpicky UI thing for me.

Comment: While the theory is correct, do note that GitLab makes no guarantees about the order of execution. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16548

Answer (score 1):

[image]Below code uses in [inheritance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)

```
Stages:
  - Step-A
  - Step-B
  - Deploy

.Perform-Step-A:
  stage: Step-A
  script:
   - echo "A"

.Perform-Step-B:
  stage: Step-B
  script:
   - echo "B"

.Perform-Deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  script:
   - echo "1"

Server1-Step-A:
  extends: .Perform-Step-A
  tags: Server-1-As-Runner //Else add SSH steps in Perfrom-A block

Server1-Step-B:
  extends: .Perform-Step-B
  tags: Server-1-As-Runner //Else add SSH steps in Perfrom-B block

Server1-Step-Deploy:
  extends: .Perform-Deploy
  tags: Server-1-As-Runner //Else add SSH steps in Perfrom-Deploy block
```

**Assumptions:**

1. You are using dedicated runners for your application and runners configured on same machine. If not please feel free to modify and ssh steps.
2. This is the conceptual building block I have answer here and can be tweak based on requirements.
3. Best worked in my case while deploying in multiple servers in one time.

***NOTE: tags are removed from the image for privacy reasons.***

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a last question: Where is the "coordinator" service ? What happen  if the runners are not on the same server ? Is the coordinator placed on each server or is it a common coordinator. Thanks

Comment: Coordinator is a heart of the GitLab CI service which builds web interface and controls the runners (build instances).In GitLab CI, Runners run the code defined in .gitlab-ci.yml. They are isolated (virtual) machines that pick up jobs through the coordinator API of GitLab CI.

So it should be [Installed](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gitlab/gitlab_install_coordinator.htm) on gitlab Server and configured on each [runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/).

Comment: if you want to deploy application on multiple server and don't want to get into the overhead of SSH key breaking.Approach I have suggest will work perfectly fine.

Example: If you want to deploy your application on multiple server then installing                     [individual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553739/gitlabci-deploy-on-multiple-servers) runner on each deployment server and using them in .gitlab-ci.yml will work.

Comment: if you do not want to use specific runner(have to use shared), then you might have to ssh from shared runner to your deployment servers followed by deployment steps.couple of examples for understanding.
https://codeburst.io/gitlab-build-and-push-to-a-server-via-ssh-6d27ca1bf7b4
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/help-deploying-same-code-to-multiple-prod-servers-at-same-time/8215