# How to create/setup cronjob in distributed manner

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cron-task

I want to create/setup cronjob on my production server. (PHP Laravel 5.7)

Let say I've 4 server if cronjob is running on one server and that server stop/crash, cron automatically start from another servers and so on..

All 4 server has there on same/identical cronjob.

All cronjob have same time.

I've googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you want the cronjob to only run at 1 server?

Comment: _if cronjob is running on one server and that server stop/crash, cron automatically start from another servers and so on.._ You probably need a cloud setup.

Answer (score -2):

Before, you need to run CI/CD in your git platform and to connect it with your project for auto deploying. Then your cronjob contents will be same in 4 servers.
[GitlabCi deploy on multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553739/gitlabci-deploy-on-multiple-servers)
https://www.virtualmetric.com/blog/how-to-diagnose-why-your-server-is-down
There is explained about how you can check if any server down and how if you can check.

After it, you need to create health checkers between servers.
https://gomachado.com/how-to-conduct-a-server-health-check/

Also, you can `enable` cron service to start automatically when server restart:

```
sudo systemctl enable cron.service
```

Comment: Please post solutions inside your answer, do not use links to 3rd party sites. If those links are unavailable (for whatever reason) this answer is of no real use

Comment: "Then your cronjob contents will be same in 4 servers" - that would mean that all four servers would run them? Sounds like a pretty bad idea if for example these cronjobs send out mails

Comment: @NicoHaase it is not my idea. Owner question wants this. Do you need condemn only?

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it. I don't see how having CI/CD has any connection to the problem, nor would `sudo systemctl enable cron.service` help to move a cronjob from a crashing server to another

Comment: Finally, all explanation should be given **in your answer** without the need to click on any external link